# Burninate the [exam] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Can we please, please, please burninate the [exam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exam) tag? It's being used for crap like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667633/can-i-get-someone-to-help-me-to-understand-this-cxc#23667633 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108145/exam-due-in-a-few-hours. From a quick scan of the questions in the tag, almost all have to do with the code needed for an exam, which makes it borderline meta-tag-y. I don't really think we need a tag for *examining* something either... so let's just burninate it.

Comment: The nearest on-topic thing that I could find related to [tag:exam] is exam certification (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002817/how-many-percent-we-need-to-pass-zend-certifieed-php5-exam which was *waaay* too old). But yes, [tag:exam] itself doesn't really helpful.

Comment: There should be a way to archive rather than delete, flagging to institutions that students are cheating.

Comment: @AndyHayden, institutions are using many different ways to both avoid and embrace information found on the web, a tag isnt going to change that.  Also, if I were a student that wanted to let my institution know I was cheating, I'd just use a cheating tag. ;)

Comment: It serves as a good way to find content for people to delete. Nothing better IMHO than an "enemy" (or just misguided user) to turn themselves in. :D

Comment: I like it how both the linked questions have been deleted already.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a handful of questions about software to run exams, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010538/exam-simulator-record-responses-and-converted-into-text) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447259/creating-online-exam-using-python) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070062/keeping-choice-questions-on-the-same-page-in-latex-exam-class). But I can't find a question where the fact that the program is related to exams is important enough to warrant a tag.

A lot of the [exam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exam) question look like they have more problems than that tag. Remember, when doing tag cleanups:

- Don't just remove the tag, edit everything else that needs editing (other tags, spelling, formatting, title, …).
- If the question should be closed, flag or vote to close. If the question is unsalvageable, don't even bother editing, the tag will disappear when the questions get deleted.

Comment: For such a legitimate use case, maybe something like "exam-software" would be better.

Comment: @Xan I could see something like `exam-software` as useful on sites like [su] and [softwarerecs.se]. But in the questions I found on SO (apart from the one about the `exam` LaTeX package), the fact that the code happens to be about exams is incidental and does not warrant a tag — it's just another question about generating a web form in PHP or whatever.

Answer (score 38):

Looks like a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me. I can't imagine many people use the exam tag to search for questions and nobody could be in expert in exam questions since they cover all sorts of different languages and topics. The questions should be tagged with the language and other relevant topics instead. I say let it burn.