# Should we add [project-euler] to everything from Project Euler?

Tags: discussion, tags, etiquette, spoilers

There are a number of questions about [Project Euler](http://www.projecteuler.net) problems that don't actually identify themselves as such.  ([The most recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26389924/744178), though I'm pretty sure I saw a question about another problem within the past week or two.)  Should users that recognize these problems as coming from Project Euler automatically add the (pre-existing) [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) tag or leave them alone?  If we do add the tag, I assume it would be necessary to identify exactly which PE problem the question is about; would putting the problem number in the edit summary be sufficient, or should it be posted in a comment on the question so that a wider audience knows exactly what the question is about?

(Full disclosure: [I've added this tag once before.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25941879/4))

Answer (score 9):

Key resource to read: [The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

The primary criteria for something being a meta tag is if one *can't* be an expert in the topic.  Can you an expert in homework? or subjective? or best-practices? No? Then its a meta tag.

> The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).

> Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. These are tags that don’t say anything by themselves – you can’t tell what the question is about unless they’re paired with some other tag (or several of them). These tags are a problem because people don’t realize this and will often use that as the question’s only tag.

(from [Please zap the meta-tags and dependent tags](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/please-zap-the-meta-tags-and-dependent-tags) on Seasoned Advice meta)

The project euler tag (or [spoj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoj)) says nothing about the actual problem but rather the context it is in.

A good question is a good question regardless of its relationship to homework, project euler, spoj, or any on line code contest.  On the other hand, a question tagged with such is often used as an 'excuse' as to why it exists at all - trying to make up for poor quality with "but its a real problem in this website."

This tag should go the way of homework.

Consider this following exchange about best-practices in the referenced blog post:

> So if a question is tagged(for example):
> [best-practices], [css], [html]

> Is it valid or not?

To which Jeff replied:

> [css] [hmtl] [best-practices]
>
> is not valid, because [best-practices] is a meta tag.
>
> What you should be asking yourself is this: for each tag you use,
> could a question with *only* that tag be valid?
>
> [css]
>
> valid, the question is about css.
>
> [html]
>
> valid, the question is about html.
>
> [best-practices]
>
> invalid, the question is about.. uh.. er.. who knows?
>
> so, just use [css] [html] and drop the meta-tag

Applying this reasoning to [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) or [spoj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoj), what is the problem about?

Glancing at a recent [spoj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoj) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118988/wrong-answer-to-spoj-prime1-in-c it is tagged with [spoj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoj) *only*.  Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088243/solution-accepted-on-spoj-but-wa-on-codechef which is tagged with [spoj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoj) and [codechef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codechef)... or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906801/how-to-terminate-our-program-in-a-very-less-time and [Spoj backpack DP explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338459/spoj-backpack-dp-explaination) which again are [spoj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoj) only questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940054/spoj-shop-giving-wrong-answer is a [spoj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoj) which isn't even about programing.  Similar poorly tagged questions exist within [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) too - [Project Euler number 35](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259393/project-euler-number-35) has only [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler).

Comment: [project-euler] tells you *even less* than, say, [spoj] or [codechef]. Those have specific sandbox environments where solution code must run (with different constraints than one's own PC) - and that is not the case with PE. With PE you just submit a short numeric answer and the system doesn't care how you got it.

Comment: It could be argued that one might be an expert in Project Euler problems.

Comment: So should I start another post to request tag burnination?

Comment: I disagree completely with this, for reasons I outline in [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274538/1709587).

Comment: Curious where "the primary criteria for something being a meta tag is if one can't be an expert in the topic" come from. "expert" doesn't appear in the [death of meta-tags blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). (But is in [many](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268111/burninate-achievements-tag/268144#268144) [other](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254915/burninate-the-exam-tag/254920#254920) [answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273083/tag-merge-or-burninate-candidates-tic-tac-toe-and-tictactoe/273086#273086) about meta-tags ... ?

Answer (score 9):

I'm posting primarily to attack [MichaelT's assertion that this tag should be burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274534/1709587).

Somebody who has worked through many or all of the Project Euler problems may want to seek out questions about them.

We have at least one other tag that is for a *problem set* - the [ruby-koans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-koans) tag - which is a useful tag since it lets people who have worked through all the koans and reached enlightenment look for questions people have about them. There are several questions that simply ask questions posed by comments in the koans, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686097/ruby-koans-why-convert-list-of-symbols-to-strings) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684446/why-is-the-shovel-operator-preferred-over-plus-equals-when-building-a) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569409/fetch-vs-when-working-with-hashes), and the tag is plainly appropriate in those cases.

We similarly have the [sicp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sicp) tag used for questions about the content of the book *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*. Could all these questions be asked without reference to their source? Yes, but knowing the source is useful information. It lets people who have read the book / done the problems seek out relevant questions.

Someone who has read an entire book or done an entire problem set is likely to have *significantly more complete* expertise in that book or problem set than somebody who works with a programming language has in the language. I have tags like Python, PHP, Objective-C and JavaScript in my favourite tags list, and have worked significantly with all of those languages professionally, but because the scope of those tags is so large I still can't answer the majority of questions about them. It's not like I've used every obscure language construct and built-in function in all of those languages, let alone every third-party library. By contrast, once I've finished a book or a problem set, I'm probably able to answer any question anybody could reasonably ask about it. As such, these tags are *much more effective* at directing people to questions they're qualified to answer than language tags are.

As such, I would absolutely keep [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler), and encourage using it to tag questions that are primarily about Project Euler problems.

Comment: The existence of similar tags does not inherently justify the existence of this one. Those are an order of magnitude smaller than this one, so they're even less likely to have been noticed and evaluated for appropriateness. And substance-wise, those specific tags no not make a convincing argument - lots of questions that really don't need the tag, and a whole lot of "My code doesn't work. `<code dump>`. Help!".

Comment: @AndrewMedico most questions are crap full stop, across all tags; I wouldn't take the existence of many crap questions on a tag as an argument against a tag existing. The only question, surely, is whether the tag is useful for people seeking out questions they are qualified to answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would say no. It strikes me as a meta-tag that does not add any *necessary* information.