# Re tag exams tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

So I stumbled upon [exams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exams) tag..

> Questions related to the computer-based generation of exams (e.g., for classical written exams or e-learning platforms like Moodle) in particular with the R package "exams".

Of the few questions there are listed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537106/what-is-the-bel-syllabus-for-member-research-staff-2017-for-electronics-and-comm , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324007/online-examination-software (put on hold few minutes ago), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898466/exam-ref-book-70-480-uses-outdated-flexbox-examples all appear to be off topic and are not related to the tag at all.

There seem to be a couple of questions related to the R language package and I do not have the knowledge to comment on it so I am not certain about burninating the tag. Can it be renamed to fit the description?

There was a similar burninate request [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254915/burninate-the-exam-tag) for [exam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exam) tag.

Comment: You should probably add to the question that the tag _was_ burninated, but later re-created.

Comment: @S.L.Barth It is `exam` and `exams`.  I cannot see the burninated tag and dont know its intended purpose.. But you are probably correct

Comment: My bad, I hadn't noticed the older tag was in the singular form.

Comment: Most of the questions mentioned in question are removed.